# Is there a short one-line way to set the margins of a component in a Python VCL GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, vcl

I know you can set each margin (Top, Right, Bottom, Left) individually like the following code:

```
self.myPanel.AlignWithMargins = True

self.myPanel.Margins.Top = 100
self.myPanel.Margins.Right = 100
self.myPanel.Margins.Bottom = 100
self.myPanel.Margins.Left = 100
```

But is there a way to set all four margins with just one line of code instead of having four lines of code (one for each margin)?

I was hoping for something like `self.myPanel.Margins = [100, 100, 100, 100]`, but this doesn't work. I get the following error `AttributeError: Error in setting property Margins (Error: Expected a Pascal object)`.

Is there a shorter/better way to set all four margins in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setBounds` function:

```
self.myPanel.Margins.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100)
```